resample_poly of one-hot encoded masking
I have these tensors:
X_test = X_unseen_flutter[0,0,:][None, :] # (Batch Size, Amplitude Length) -> (1, 3208)
y_true = y_unseen_flutter[0,0,:][None, :] # (Batch Size, Mask Length, Num of Classes) -> (1, 3208, 4) (One-Hot Encoded)

I can resample the X_test, but I have no idea for the y_true:
from scipy.signal import resample_poly

X_test_resampled = resample_poly(X_test, up=512, down=3208, axis=1) # (1, 512)
y_true_resampled = # ??? I expect shape (1, 512, 4)

What is the equivalent of resample_poly but for the one-hot encoded label?
I expect there is a function to do that where it accepts tensor, up, down, mask_axis, class_axis

Suppose you have a one-hot vector at time step t=0 of [1, 0], and another at time step t=10 of [0, 1]. Suppose that the resampling needs to compute the correct value of the one-hot vector at time step t=1. Would it be correct to say that the one-hot vector should be [1, 0], since that is what the nearest one-hot vector is? Would it be correct to say that the one-hot vector at t=1 should be [0.9, 0.1], since that is a linear interpolation of the vectors at t=0 and t=10? Is [0.9, 0.1] a valid output, or are you expecting either 0 or 1?

It must be nearest one-hot vector, not the linear interpolation, basically this is about retaining indices information. But I think I have solved it with just using numpy step array indexing
